# Submitting hidden form input field changed by jquery in Angular Dart

Tags: angular, angular-dart

An angular Dart  form has this input field

```
<input  id="idX"   type="number" step="any" [(ngModel)]="mdl.x" ngControl="slrLocPtXCtrl" >
```

If I change the value of this field  via javascript, it  shows  the  changed  value on the form  but when I submit the  form, model mdl.x  is  not  updated  with the  changed value.

java script  is -

```
 $("#idX").val(20).trigger("change"); // trigger(input)  also  does not work
```

How can I get the model to  reflect the  changed value ?   Also  once this  starts  working , I want to  make this  input field  hidden.  What extra changes would I need to  get it  work ?

Answer (score 0):

in your typescript write this.mdl.x = 20. Why you are changing textbox value through javascript? because as soon as you will update property in typescript, it will automatically display in input box.